# Convert Spanish grades to English scale?

Tags: grades, grading

I'm a English citizen which has been living in Spain for the past 7 years (I'm currently 15 years old in case you're wondering) and I plan to move back to England at the end of this school year.
Can anyone tell me what's classified as a C in percentage? And a B? A 50%? A 60%? In Spain the grade scale's from 1-10, 5 is classified as the minimum pass and 10 is classified as excellent. Thank you guys for helping me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about school and not about academia.